# Google Recaptcha on explicit render for mulitple forms it returns "Invalid key type" error

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, captcha

I'm having some issues on implementing Google recaptcha validation on a single page having multiple forms.
Reading many posts on the argument has led me to this design, that includes the possibility of using html5 validations before submitting the recaptcha validAtion:

HTML side

```
<head>
....
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
...
<form id="contactFrm1">
...
<div id="RecaptchaField1" class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="formSubmit1"></div>
...
</form>
...
...
<form id="contactFrm2">
...
<div id="RecaptchaField2" class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="formSubmit2"></div>
...
</form>
..
</body>
```

Javascript Side

```
<script>
var CaptchaCallback = function() {
    jQuery('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
            var widgetId = grecaptcha.enterprise.render(el, {'sitekey' : SITE_KEY});
        jQuery(this).attr('data-widget-id', widgetId);
    });
};
    
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#submit").click(function(){
    $('#contactFrm1').submit(function(event) {
    if (!grecaptcha.enterprise.getResponse(jQuery('#RecaptchaField1').attr('data-widget-id'))){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent form submit
        grecaptcha.enterprise.execute(jQuery('#RecaptchaField1').attr('data-widget-id'));
                }
    });
    formSubmit = function() {
    $('#contactFrm1').submit();
            }
    }); 
});

//same logic for the second form
</script>
```

On rendering the page shows, for both of captcha widgets, "Note for site owner: Invalid key type".

I'm sure about the validity of the key, due to the fact that using the "not explicit" rendering do not return any kind of error and, at last, the key is valid from the Google administration settings.

Can you please help me to understand what is wrong with this solution?
Thanks in advance

Some posts showed that the problem should be on the execute methods, that it's expecting the widget_id, in a first version I didn't provide it, but after introducing it the result hasn't changed.
Google documentation is not really exhaustive...

Comment: Guys, I have an update, the issue seems to be solved but I do not clearly understand. The issue was the type of the key and that's the point: I was implementing at the beginning the key score model without human interaction, in another page with just 1 form, without obviously the needs of doing the explicit render, that solution worked as well. Now, forcing the render, mandatory for N forms in the same page, changed automatically the captcha type, switching to human interaction mode? At last, the main point remains: how can I integrate multiple forms in the Non human interaction mode? KR.